# Writing and reading to a file using streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream

The below code writes to a file whatever I type in the console. It also simultaneously reads from the same file and displays whatever that's in the file.

Everything I type in the console is saved in the file. I manually went and checked it. But whatever I type doesn't get displayed simultaneously.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Wstream = fs.createWriteStream('./testfile.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'});
const Rstream = fs.createReadStream('./testfile.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'});
process.stdin.pipe(Wstream);
Rstream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Why isn't this the same as the following?

```
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [read stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) will be closed when the data in `./testfile.txt` is fully piped. It will not wait for additional entries or changes.

You can use [`fs.watch`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener), to listen for file changes or even better use something easier like [tail-stream](https://github.com/Juul/tail-stream) or [node-tail](https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail).

Comment: Oh ok, I'll try `fs.watch` and the others. Thank you. But still, shouldn't it atleast display what was already inside the file?

Comment: The default options of `fs.createWriteStream` will overwrite the file, so `./testfile.txt` will be empty when the read stream is created. If you want to append to the file you can use `fs.createWriteStream('./testfile.txt', { flags: 'a' })`.